# Ошибка при попытке создать сущность

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, asp.net-web-api

Есть две сущности, Administrator и User. Между ними связь 1:1. При попытке создать сущность, вылезает непонятная мне ошибка:
[image: Ошибка]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код модели Administrator:

```
public class Administrator
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Surname { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public int PassportSeries { get; set; }
    public int PassportNumber { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public User User { get; set; } = new User();
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}
```

Код модели User:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Password { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Role { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public Administrator? Administrator { get; set; } = new Administrator();
    public Client? Client { get; set; } = new Client();
    public Coach? Coach { get; set; } = new Coach();

}
```

Код метода регистрации:

```
public async Task<ServiceResponse<GetAdminDto>> RegisterAdmin(RegisterAdminDto request)
{
    var response = new ServiceResponse<GetAdminDto>();
    try
    {
        var newUser = _mapper.Map<User>(request);
        newUser.Role = "Administrator";
        var newAdmin = _mapper.Map<Administrator>(request);
        newAdmin.User = newUser;
        _context.AddRange(newUser, newAdmin);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        response.Data = _mapper.Map<GetAdminDto>(newAdmin);
        return response;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        response.Success = false;
        response.Data = null;
        response.Message = ex.Message;
        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: Не только с этим методом так, другие такое же исключение выбрасывают. По описанию проблема в переполнении стека. Но почему он переполняется? Все работало, я просто добавил новую сущность и все...Я не понимаю

Comment: а если убрать из классов  = new User(); и  = new Administrator(); ? возможно при создании одного объекта он создает в нем другой а тот в свою очередь опять внутри первый создает

Comment: @Nikolay может быть вы знаете как это исправить, просто я не думал, что так будет происходить…

Comment: @ТёмаKornishon а вы не знаете почему так происходит ?

Comment: сработало? в ответе ниже всё написано

Comment: @ТёмаKornishon да, все сработало, спасибо. Не знаете как тогда убрать предупреждение на nullable тип?

Comment: возможно вы имеете ввиду убрать "?" после указания типа. классы итак nullable

Comment: @ТёмаKornishon ну я имею ввиду, например в классе Administrator, у свойства public User User { get; set; } висит предупреждение. Если сделаю User? User предупреждение пропадет, но тогда это свойство будет необязательным. Если явно инициализировать будет вот этот вот цикл создания объектов. Как мне лучше убрать предупреждение?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У вас переполнение стека случилось. У вас иницилизаторы полей Administrator и User уходят в бесконечный цикл создания друг друга